# My javascript "slideshow" isnt working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a small part of a website that I'm experimenting with. Anyway I'm learning Javascript and I decided to experiment by making an extremely simple "slideshow", but whenever I run this in the browser (Mozilla Firefox 42), the browser crashes. I'm wondering if anyone could tell me whats wrong or possibly give me a better way of making this(I'm sure there is but I couldn't find one). Also I know I can make this in jQuery but I want to try this out with pure Javascript.

I have also tried this on Chrome and Opera.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //I will use javascript to make the "slideshow" on mainSection
 function loop() {
 var BACKGROUND = document.getElementById("Introduction");
 var SECTION1 = document.getElementById("mainSection");
 var SECTION2 = document.getElementById("section2");
 var SECTION3 = document.getElementById("section3");
 var i = 1;
 
 while (i <= 3) {
  i = i + 0.0001;
  SECTION1.style.display="block";
  SECTION2.style.display="none";
  SECTION3.style.display="none";
 }
 
 while (i <= 6) {
  i = i + 0.0001;
  SECTION1.style.display="none";
  SECTION2.style.display="block";
  SECTION3.style.display="none";
 }
 
 while (i <= 9) {
  i = i + 0.0001;
  SECTION1.style.display="none";
  SECTION2.style.display="none";
  SECTION3.style.display="block";
 }
 
 while (i = 9) {
  i = 1;
 }
}
 
 
</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loop();">
  <header id="Introduction">
  
   <section id="mainSection">
    <h1>Welcome to the Ipsum Hotel.</h1>
    <p>This is where thought and precision goes<br />
    towards the comfort of our customers.<br /></p>
   </section>
   <!--This will be used to make a slideshow-->
   <section id="section2">
    <p><strong>Free Wifi!</strong></p>
    <p>Free wifi is included in all of our guest<br />
    packages from Economy to Deluxe<br /></p>
   </section>
   
   <section id="section3">
    <p><strong>Free Hot Breakfast</strong></p>
    <p>Included with any of our guest packages is<br />
    a hearty breakfast. You can also get a personalized<br />
    omelet at our omelet bar.<br /></p>
   </section>
  </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `while (i = 9) { i = 1; }` looks very wrong. Perhaps you meant `if (i == 9) { i = 1; }`? But then, you're not using `i` for anything after that. Should `loop()` perhaps actually… *loop*?

Comment: … Moreover, those are blocking, long-running loops. I doubt the browser *crashes*, but it most likely *freezes*. You might want to use something less blocking, e.g. `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setInterval`. As mentioned in the comments, a while loop will block all page operations and tax your CPU. `setInterval` is designed specifically for handling timing operations in a more resource-friendly manner.

```
var SECTION1 = document.getElementById("mainSection");
var SECTION2 = document.getElementById("section2");
var SECTION3 = document.getElementById("section3");
var sections = [SECTION1, SECTION2, SECTION3];
var activeSection = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  // If we are past the end of list, reset to first element
  if (activeSection >= sections.length) {
    activeSection = 0;
  }

  // Mark only the activeSection as visible
  sections.forEach(function(section, idx) {
    section.style.display = activeSection === idx ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
  activeSection += 1;
}, 3000);
```

This will loop over each section every three seconds (at the least, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval for more info about how timers work in the browser). Once the last section is reached, it resets to the first section.